# why i'm getting same logPrefix in WebFilter between different requests?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm using spring-framework with spring-boot 2.1.5.RELEASE.

For logging request and response, I create `LogFilter` which implements `WebFilter` and write log for all requests like below code.

```java
@Slf4j
@Component
public class LogFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String logPrefix = exchange.getLogPrefix();
        String path = exchange.getRequest().getURI().getPath();
        String remoteAddr = "(" + exchange.getRequest().getRemoteAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress() + ")";
        String method = exchange.getRequest().getMethodValue();
        log.info("{}HTTP {} {} {}", logPrefix, method, path, remoteAddr);

        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
}
```

I expect that `logPrefix` from `ServerWebExchange` is unique string 
 for each requests. but actually it looks like reused or generated same string among the requests. Therefore log file is like below.
(it seems like logPrefix is unique string for each Thread not each requests)

```
16:39:03.103 [http-epoll-8]  INFO [             LogFilter:35   ] - [ca47e591] HTTP GET /monitor/l7check 
16:39:08.123 [http-epoll-8]  INFO [             LogFilter:35   ] - [ca47e591] HTTP GET /monitor/l7check 
16:39:08.480 [http-epoll-1]  INFO [             LogFilter:35   ] - [e3546756] HTTP POST /monitor/l7check
16:39:13.127 [http-epoll-8]  INFO [             LogFilter:35   ] - [ca47e591] HTTP GET /monitor/l7check 
16:39:18.126 [http-epoll-8]  INFO [             LogFilter:35   ] - [ca47e591] HTTP GET /monitor/l7check 
16:39:23.123 [http-epoll-2]  INFO [             LogFilter:35   ] - [5a56750e] HTTP GET /monitor/l7check 
16:39:28.122 [http-epoll-8]  INFO [             LogFilter:35   ] - [ca47e591] HTTP GET /monitor/l7check
```

this situation is normal?

if so, how to generate unique `logPrefix` for each requests?

Comment: this seems to be a known issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22039

Comment: @ThomasAndolf oh..ok. i will follow this issue.. thanks!!